# How do I use itertools.cycle with multiple objects?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, python-itertools

I'm trying to cycle the colour of a button when pressed in Tkinter through the colours defined in the `itertools.cycle` iterator:

```
colour=itertools.cycle('blue', 'green', 'orange', 'red', 'yellow', 'white')

def changeColour(button):
    button.configure(bg = next(colour))

LT = Button(root, width=16, height=8, bg = 'white', command=lambda: changeColour(LT))
LT.place(x=10, y=10)

LM = Button(root, width=16, height=8, bg = 'white', command=lambda: changeColour(LM))
LM.place(x=10, y=150)

LB = Button(root, width=16, height=8, bg = 'white', command=lambda: changeColour(LB))
LB.place(x=10, y=290)
```

However, each button press affects the starting position in the iterable for the next button press, meaning each button will jump to the value of `next(colour)` after the one assigned to the previously clicked button. I'm trying to make each button perform the full cycle of background colours independant of the other button's current colour. How could I achieve this?

Comment: seperate `cycle`s for each button?

Comment: Why on earth would you *expect* `button+colour` to work?! It may seem inefficient, but if you want each button to have a separate cycle of colours, you don't have a choice. And I note you still have a lot of duplication in your code - it would be easier and feel less efficient if you factored that out.

Comment: Sorry @jonrsharpe could you give me an example? I've only just stumbled upon `lambda` and cycles in my last question

Comment: So you expected e.g. `LT + colour` to result in the object `LTcolour`? I can't see any rational basis to even try that, frankly.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Brilliant. Thanks for the help

Comment: You should read e.g. http://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html, which covers the basics of names pretty well. If you added strings (`'LT' + 'colour'`) and used e.g. `locals` or a dictionary that would help, but adding *names* makes no sense (if that worked, how would you add anything that wasn't a literal?)

Comment: @jonrsharpe Absolutely. My mistake. I'm trying to get a grasp of Tkinter, could OOP factor out some of this code repetition?

Comment: @Eddie potentially, yes - you could make a `Button` subclass (e.g. `class ColourCycleButton(tk.Button)`) that encapsulates all of that logic, then just create a few of those.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to have a separate `cycle` for each button if you want them to be independent. One way to do this would be to create a function factory for building the functions you need to call:

```
COLOURS = ('blue', 'green', 'orange', 'red', 'yellow', 'white')

def colour_changer(button, colours=COLOURS):
    """Creates a callback to change the colour of the button."""
    colour_cycle = itertools.cycle(colours)
    def command():
        """The callback to change a single button's colour."""
        button.configure(bg=next(colour_cycle))
    return command
```

Then you call this after creating each button:

```
LT = Button(root, width=16, height=8, bg = 'white')
LT.configure(command=colour_changer(LT))
```

You could also look into bindings, which will pass the button into the callback for you.

Answer (score 0):

Each button knows it current background color.  The following uses a dictionary to map current color to the next color in a cyclic fashion.

```
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()

colors = ('blue', 'green', 'orange', 'red', 'yellow', 'white', 'blue')
cd = dict(zip(colors, colors[1:]))
#print(cd)

def changeColour(button):
    button['bg'] = cd[button['bg']]

LT = Button(root, width=16, height=8, bg = 'white',
            command=lambda: changeColour(LT))
LT.place(x=10, y=10)

LM = Button(root, width=16, height=8, bg = 'white',
            command=lambda: changeColour(LM))
LM.place(x=10, y=150)

LB = Button(root, width=16, height=8, bg = 'white',
            command=lambda: changeColour(LB))
LB.place(x=10, y=290)

root.mainloop()
```